# Find all differences in an array in O(n)

Tags: java, c, arrays, algorithm

Question: Given a sorted array A find all possible difference of elements from A.

My solution:

```
for (int i=0; i<n-1; ++i) {
  for (int j=i+1; j<n; ++j) {
    System.out.println(Math.abs(ai-aj));
  }
}
```

Sure, it's O(n^2), but I don't over count things at all. I looked online and I found this: http://www.careercup.com/question?id=9111881. It says you can't do better, but at an interview I was told you can do O(n). Which is right?

Comment: I would be wary of taking a job at this company... They'll probably expect you to solve NP-complete problems in P time... ;-)

Comment: My guess would be that either you or the interviewer overlooked or overheard an additional condition.

Comment: Define n to be the number of differences (size of output rather than size of input). Hey presto - it's now O(n).

Comment: for **sorted** array it's trivial to find duplicate elements, if the previous element is equal to the current == duplication. perhaps the question was not properly asked?

Comment: @bestsss This question has nothing to do with looking for duplicates.

Comment: this is clear and if it's not about the sum of |ai-aj|, then it's plain wrong to expect O(n)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A first thought is that you aren't using the fact that the array is sorted. Let's assume it's in increasing order (decreasing can be handled analogously).

We can also use the fact that the differences telescope (i>j):

```
a_i - a_j = (a_i - a_(i-1)) + (a_(i-1) - a_(i-2)) + ... + (a_(j+1) - a_j)
```

Now build a new sequence, call it s, that has the simple difference, meaning `(a_i - a_(i-1))`. This takes only one pass (`O(n)`) to do, and you may as well skip over repeats, meaning skip `a_i` if `a_i = a_(i+1)`.

All possible differences `a_i-a_j` with `i>j` are of the form `s_i + s_(i+1) + ... + s_(j+1)`. So maybe if you count that as having found them, then you did it in `O(n)` time. To print them, however, may take as many as `n(n-1)/2` calls, and that's definitely `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Ok. I see how this uses the fact that the array is sorted because you don't have to worry about absolute values. I still don't think it's really O(n), but it's probably what he had in mind. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

For example for an array with the elements *{2<sup>1</sup>, 2<sup>2</sup>, ..., 2<sup>n</sup>}* there are *n⋅(n-1)/2* possible differences, and no two of them are equal. So there are *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* differences.

Since you have to enumerate all of them, you also need at least *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* time.

Comment: That's what the answer in the link I gave said, but the interviewer was pretty insistent that there's a O(n) solution.

Comment: Since `a[last] - a[first]` is the largest possible difference, it is also (one less than) the maximum possible number of difference values. So that's linear in something, just not in the size of the original array. Maybe there's a way to check whether each difference in turn actually occurs in time linear to the number of potential differences, but I can't think of it ATM.

Comment: Yes, O(n^2) is the worst case, but note that some differences may appear multiple times. A problem comes up: is there an output-sensitive algorithm, with O(k) time complexity (or similar), where k is the number of unique differences? This means for example, for special inputs where k=O(n), the algorithm would take just O(n).

Comment: For example, for inputs of the form [i, i, ..., i], where i!=0, there are exactly n-1 differences.

Answer (score 1):

sorted or unsorted doesn't matter, if you have to calculate each difference there is no way to do it in less then n^2,

the question was asked wrong, or you just do O(n) and then print 42 the other N times :D

Answer (score 1):

You can get another counter-example by assuming the array contents are random integers before sorting. Then the chance that two differences, Ai - Aj vs Ak - Al, or even Ai - Aj vs Aj - Ak, are the same is too small for there to be only O(n) distinct differences Ai - Aj.

Given that, the question to your interviewer is to explain the special circumstances that allow an O(n) solution. One possibility is that the array values are all numbers in the range 0..n, because in this case the maximum absolute difference is only n.

I can do this in O(n lg n) but not O(n). Represent the array contents by an array of size n+1 with element i set to 1 where there is a value i in the array. Then use FFT to convolve the array with itself - there is a difference Ai - Aj = k where the kth element of the convolution is non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

If the interviewer is fond of theoretical games, perhaps he was thinking of using a table of inputs and results? *Any* problem with a limit on the size of the input, and that has a known solution, can be solved by table lookup. Given that you have first created and stored that table, which might be *large*.

So if the array size is limited, the problem can be solved by table lookup, which (given some assumptions) can even be done in constant time. Granted, even for a maximum array size of *two* (assuming 32-bit integers) the table will not fit in a normal computer's memory, or on the disks. For larger max sizes of the array, you're into "won't fit in the known universe" size. But, theoretically, it can be done.

(But in reality, I think that Jens Gustedt's comment is more likely.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can surely do that its a little tricky method.
to find differances in O(n) you will need to use BitSet(C++) or any similar Data Structure in respective language.

Initialize two bitset say A and B
You can do as follows:
For each iteration through array:
1--store consecutive differance in BitSet A
2--LeftShift B
3--store consecutive differance in BitSet B
4--take A=A or B

for example I have given code-
Here N is Size of array

```
for (int i=1;i<N;i++){
    int diff = arr[i]-arr[i-1];
    A[diff]=1;
    B<<=diff;
    B[diff]=1;
    A=A | B;
}
```

Bits in A which are 1 will be the differances.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the array need to be sorted

lets think a sorted array ar =  **{1,2,3,4}**

so what we were doing at the O(n^2)

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++) sum+=abs(ar[i]-ar[j]);
```

if we do the operations here elaborately then it will look like below

```
when i = 0 | sum = sum + {(2-1)+(3-1)+(4-1)}                   
when i = 1 | sum = sum + {(3-2)+(4-2)}               
when i = 2 | sum = sum + {(4-3)}
```

if we write them all

```
sum = ( -1-1-1) + (2+ -2-2) + (3+3 -3) + (4+4+4 )
```

we can see that

the number at index 0 is added to the sum for 0 time and substracted from the sum for 3 time.
the number at index 1 is added to the sum for 1 time and substracted from the sum for 2 time.
the number at index 2 is added to the sum for 2 time and substracted from the sum for 1 time.
the number at index 3 is added to the sum for 3 time and substracted from the sum for 0 time.

so for we can say that,

```
the number at index i will be added to the sum for i time 
and will be substracted from the sum for (n-i)-1 time
```

Then the generalized expression for
each element will be

```
sum = sum + (i*a[i]) – ((n-i)-1)*a[i];
```