# Find all pairwise differences in an array of distinct integers less than 1e5

Tags: c++, fft, convolution

Given an array of distinct positive integers **≤ 10<sup>5</sup>** , I need to find differences of all pairs.

I don't really need to count frequency of every difference, just unique differences.

Using brute force, this can be approached by checking all possible pairs. However, this would not be efficient enough considering the size of array (as all elements are distinct so the maximum size is **10<sup>5</sup>** ). This would lead to **O (n<sup>2</sup>)** complexity.

I need to exploit the property of this array that the differences are **≤ 10<sup>5</sup>**

So my another approach :

- The array elements can be represented using another hash array where the indices representing array elements will be 1 and rest will be 0.
- This hash array is represented as a polynomial with all coefficients as 1 and exponents as respective hash values.
- Now clone this polynomial and make another polynomial with exponents negated.
  If now these polynomials are multiplied, all the positive exponents in the result correspond to differences required.

However this multiplication is something that I am not certain how to efficiently implement. I think *FFT* can be used as it helps multiply two polynomials in **O(n log n)** complexity. But it requires positive exponents.

Please provide with suggestions on how to proceed now?

I also came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64220745/13162739) algorithm, which uses *FFT* to find pairwise differences in **O(n log n)**, however I can't understand how the algorithm is working. It seems that it is trying to find [all possible sums](https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/fft.html#toc-tgt-9).

A proof of this algorithm would be appreciated.

Comment: how is this not a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64220374/find-all-differences-in-an-array-in-onlogn-where-n-is-the-max-range-of-element/64220745#64220745 ?

Comment: I can't seem to comment there to ask the question owing to less reputation, so I asked here.

Comment: Express how your question is different, otherwise you have the same question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all differences in an array in O(nlogn) where n is the max range of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64220374/find-all-differences-in-an-array-in-onlogn-where-n-is-the-max-range-of-element)

Comment: @PasserBy Essentially, I would like to know the proof of the algorithm mentioned in the given answer, i.e. why would the algorithm give the correct answer.