# Numbers of common distinct difference

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, set, c++17

Given two array A and B. Task to find the number of common distinct (difference of elements in two arrays).
Example :

```
A=[3,6,8]
B=[1,6,10]

so we get differenceSet for A
differenceSetA=[abs(3-6),abs(6-8),abs(8-3)]=[3,5,2]
similiarly
differenceSetB=[abs(1-6),abs(1-10),abs(6-10)]=[5,9,4]

Number of common elements=Intersection :{differenceSetA,differenceSetB}={5}
Answer= 1
```

My approach O(N^2)

```
int commonDifference(vector<int> A,vector<int> B){
    int n=A.size();
    int m=B.size();
    unordered_set<int> differenceSetA;
    unordered_set<int> differenceSetB;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++){
            differenceSetA.insert(abs(A[i]-A[j]));
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<m;j++){
            differenceSetB.insert(abs(B[i]-B[j]));
        }
    }
    int count=0;
    for(auto &it:differenceSetA){
        if(differenceSetB.find(it)!=differenceSetB.end()){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
    
}
```

Please provide suggestions for optimizing the approach in O(N log N)

Comment: For a given array, you can find the set of diferences in O(n logn): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64220374/find-all-differences-in-an-array-in-onlogn-where-n-is-the-max-range-of-element/64220745?noredirect=1#comment113643521_64220745

Comment: @Damien - please add an answer including this, then some logic to find the common values from it. So OP can approve and upvote if he so desires

Comment: I forgot to mention that this approach will be efficient if the range of input values is not too large. The algorithm is (n log n), but here n is the value range, not the size of the input array

Comment: @Damien, I'm facing difficulty in implementing this approach. May you please help me?

Comment: Il will try to post an answer, with some details. What is the data range?

Comment: @Damien N,M<=10^5

Comment: @shapiroyaacov I finally proposed an answer, while trying to avoid plagiarism!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If n is the maximum range of a input array, then the set of all differences of a given array can be obtained in O(n logn), as explained in this SO post: [find all differences in a array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64220374/find-all-differences-in-an-array-in-onlogn-where-n-is-the-max-range-of-element)

Here is a brief recall of the method, with a few additional practical implementation details:

> 1. Create an array `Posi` of length `2*n = 2*range = 2*(Vmax - Vmin + 1)`, where elements whose index matches an element of the input are set to 1, other elements are set to 0. This can be created in O(m), where `m` is the size of the array.
>    For example, given in input array [1,4,5] of size `m`, we create an array [1,0,0,1,1].

```
Initialisation: Posi[i] = 0 for all i (i = 0 to 2*n)
Posi[A[i] - Vmin] = 1 (i = 0 to m)
```

> 2. Calculate the autocorrelation function of array `Posi[]`. This can be classically performed in three sub-steps
>
> 2.1 Calculate the FFT (size 2*n) of `Posi[]`array: `Y[] = FFT(Posi)`
>
> 2.2 Calculate the square amplitude of the result: `Y2[k] = Y[k] * conj([Y[k])`
>
> 2.3 Calculate the Inverse FFT of the result `Diff[]` = IFFT (Y2[])`

A few details are worth being mentioned here:

- The reason why a size `2*n` was selected, and not a size `n`, if that, is `d` is a valid difference, then `-d` is also a valid difference. The results corresponding to negative differences are available at positions `i >= n`
- If you find more easy to perform FFT with a size a-power-of-two, than you can replace the size `2*n` with a value `n2k = 2^k`, with `n2k >= 2*n`

> 3. The non-null differences correspond to non-null values in the array `Diff[]`:

```
`d` is a difference if `Diff[d] > 0`
```

Another important details is that a classical FFT is used (float calculations), then you encounter little errors. To take it into account, it is important to replace the IFFT output `Diff[]` with integer rounded values of the real part.

All that concerns one array only. As you want to calculate the number of common differences, then you have to:

> - calculate the arrays `Diff_A[]` and `Diff_B[]` for both sets `A` and `B` and then:

```
count = 0;
if (Diff_A[d] != 0) and (Diff_B[d] != 0) then count++;
```

---

**A little Bonus**

In order to avoid a plagiarism of the mentioned post, here is an additional explanation about the way to get the differences of one set, with the help of the FFT.

The input array `A = {3, 6, 8}` can mathematically be represented by the following *z* transform:

```
 A(z) = z^3 + z^6 + z^8
```

Then the corresponding z-transform of the difference array is equal to the polynomial product:

```
D(z) = A(z) * A(z*) = (z^3 + z^6 + z^8) (z^(-3) + z^(-6) + z^(-8)) 
= z^(-5) + z^(-3) + z^(-2) + 3 + z^2 + z^3 + z^5
```

Then, we can note that `A(z)` is equal to a FFT of size N of the sequence `[0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1]` by taking:

```
z = exp (-i * 2 PI/ N), with i = sqrt(-1)
```

Note that here we consider the classical FFT in C, the complex field.

It is certainly possible to perform calculation in a Galois field, and then no rounding errors, as it is done for example to implement "classical" multiplications (with z = 10) for a large number of digits. This seems over-skilled here.