# Using FFT to find all possible sum

Tags: algorithm, fft

Given array A[] and B[], to find how frequently each possible sums A[i] + B[j] appears we can use FFT

For example
A = [1,2,3], B = [2,4].

The sum 3 can be obtained in 1 way, sum 4 : 1 way, sum 5 : 2 ways, sum 6 : 1 way, sum 7 : 1 way

The way we can do this is to construct two polynomials, P and Q  with their power corresponding to the element of the array. And apply the regular FFT.

[image]

So is there an efficient way of backtracking the numbers that forms the above. To elaborate, we know 3 can be formed in 1 way. But how do we know which two numbers form it?

One way to do it would be the classic two sum algorithm, i.e given an array and a target sum. Find the pairs that create the sum. Which is O(n)
Given we can have N different targets, the resulting algorithm is O(n^2). But I want to keep it under O(nlogn).

Comment: I don't understand question 1. For question 2 can't you just take the square of the corresponding polynomial?

Comment: I'll admit I never did signal-processing in school, but isn't FFT for input data in a *continuous* domain? But your question involves discrete integers... that doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: "Can FFT be used to find this?" - if it can be then it wouldn't be optimal. It's much quicker to solve that second problem with a dynamic-programming solution.

Comment: I don't think that's true. One example would be a fast way to multiply polynomial in O(nlogn). You can certainly use it for discrete integer. In fact, there's Discrete Fourier transform, FFT is just the fast algorithm to do it.

Comment: @Dai Yes, you're right DP would be much easier for this one example. But there are problems that needs FFT and I am just trying to get a better understanding of the algorithm from easier examples. For example: https://atcoder.jp/contests/agc047/tasks/agc047_c

Comment: @scholcode If you want to learn about FFT/DFT I think you'd be better-off using a _real-world_ dataset rather than contriving your own scenario, such as for a Software-Defined Radio application.

Comment: Your problem seems quite similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64220374/find-all-differences-in-an-array-in-onlogn-where-n-is-the-max-range-of-element). Note that the complexity is O(nlogn) effectively, but here, `n` is the maximum size (the range), not the size of the array. So yes, a FFT/IFFT process can be used. Its efficiency versus DP depends on the parameters: array sizes, range... I provided additional information on this subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64301458/numbers-of-common-distinct-difference/64304626#64304626)

Comment: @Damien. Great answer! I got it now. However, I want to ask if you can explain how to efficiently find out the numbers that create the sum? For example, if 3 can be formed in 1 way, how can we find out which two numbers? I edited the post, on the bottom I proposed a method but I think there should be a more efficient method.

Comment: The FFT methods can provide the sum values and the associated multiplicities. At first glance,  I can't see how to use the FFT to get the corresponding pairs. Sorrry, I didn't understand it was your goal.