# Improving a solution

Tags: c++, vector, combinatorics

The description of a task goes like this:
We have **n** numbers, and we have to find quantity of unique sums of all the pairs in the array.
For example:

```
3 2 5 6 3  
The sums of all the pairs(non-repeated) are 5 9 8 6 8 7 5 11 9 8  
Unique are 5 9 8 6 7 11  
Therefore output is 6
```

I have come up with this really primitive, and time-consuming (meaning complexity) solution:

```
int n = 0;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> vec(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> vec[i];
    }
    vector<int> sum;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++)
        {
            sum.push_back(vec[i] + vec[j]);
        }
    }
    sort(sum.begin(), sum.end());
    for (int i = 0; i < sum.size()-1;)
    {
        if (sum[i] == sum[i + 1]) sum.erase(sum.begin() + i);
        else i++;
    }
    cout << endl << sum.size();
```

I feel like there could be a solution using **Combinatorics** or something easier. I have thought a lot and couldn't think of anything. So my request is if anyone can improve the solution.

Comment: Your last loop could be replaced by [`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Hm, that's an interesting thing you taught me. I'll utilize that. Otherwise, no idea how I could somehow make the solution better by time complexity? I feel that the for's are really taking up a lot

Comment: Also, you can easily calculate the number of elements for the vector `sum` and reserve or resize it appropriately before adding elements to it.

Comment: Or you can use `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` instead of a vector.

Comment: @molbdnilo In sets, we should have unique objects only right? So If I were to make sum a std::set, and then wrote sums into it, it would only give me the unique ones right?

Comment: If the number of values is large, but the maximum value is not very large, you can try using FFT, in the same spirit of what is done to calculate the difference values, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64220374/find-all-differences-in-an-array-in-onlogn-where-n-is-the-max-range-of-element)

Comment: @DavidPetriashvili Yes, insert the sums into a set (or unordered_set) and the number of unique elements would be `set.size()`

Comment: @DavidPetriashvili That's pretty much the definition of a set, yes. (Unfortunately, the huge complexity factor is the quadratic addition loop. If you want real improvement, that's where you need to focus. Also unfortunately, I can't think of anything clever...)

Comment: @molbdnilo Oh my lord, I... haven't done programming in C++ for a long time and rarely did I ever use anything else than std::vector, because I didn't learn the whole STL, but later on I did but never utilized them. That's actually very clever. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Damien I'll try to see how I can use that solution you linked, thanks!

Comment: @Blastfurnace I guess your comment was for David, not for me !:)

Comment: @Damien Oops, sorry about that.

Comment: @molbdnilo That damned O(n^2) is my nightmare! And I like wrote down the sums bruteforcely and looked at the quantities and just made a parallel with Combinatorics and thought I could find a solution from that way.

Comment: You could implement the different improvements suggested here, then make sure it really works, and post on [the Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get a review of the code and perhaps more optimization tips.

Comment: And as a possible optimization, how about parallelization? Perhaps using [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't want to complicate stuff. This is a simple training task given to me to train and yeah. I wanna do it in simple terms. Massive thanks for the recommendation tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above what you need it is difficult to do this without computing the sum of all pairs, so I am not going to handle that, I am just going to advise about efficient data structures.

#### Analysis of your solution

Your code adds everything in advance `O(n^2)` then sorts `O(n^2 log(n))`, then remove duplicates. But since you are erasing from a vector, that ultimately has [complexity](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/) linear with the number of elements to the end of the list. It means that the second loop will make the complexity of your algorithm `O(n^4)`.

You can count the unique elements in a sorted array without removing

```cpp
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < sum.size()-1; ++i)
{
        if (sum[i] != sum[i + 1]) ++count
}
```

This change alone makes your algorithm complexity `O(n^2 log n)`.

#### Alternatives without sorting.

Here are alternatives that `O(n^2)` and storage depending on the range of the input values instead of the length of the vector (except for the last).

I am testing with 1000 elements smaller between 0 and 10000

```cpp
vector<int> vec;
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i){
    vec.push_back(rand() % 10000);
}
```

Your implementation `sum_pairs1(vec)` (18 seconds)

```cpp
int sum_pairs1(const vector<int> &vec){
    vector<int> sum;
    int n = vec.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++)
        {
            sum.push_back(vec[i] + vec[j]);
        }
    }
    sort(sum.begin(), sum.end());
    for (int i = 0; i < sum.size()-1;)
    {
        if (sum[i] == sum[i + 1]) sum.erase(sum.begin() + i);
        else i++;
    }
    return sum.size();
}
```

If you know the range for the sum of the values you can use a bitset, efficient use of memory `sum_pairs2<20000>(vec)` (0.016 second).

```cpp
template<size_t N>
int sum_pairs2(const vector<int> &vec){
    bitset<N> seen;
    int n = vec.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++)
        {
            seen[vec[i] + vec[j]] = true;
        }
    }
    return seen.count();
}
```

If you know that the maximum sum is not so high (the vector is not very sparse), but you don't know at compilation time you can use a vector, you can keep track of minimum and maximum to allocate the minimum possible and also supporting negative values.

```cpp
int sum_pairs2b(const vector<int> &vec){
    int VMAX = vec[0];
    int VMIN = vec[0]
    for(auto v : vec){
        if(VMAX < v) VMAX = v;
        else if(VMIN > v) VMIN = v;
    }
    vector<bool> seen(2*(VMAX - VMIN) + 1);
    int n = vec.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++)
        {
            seen[vec[i] + vec[j] - 2*VMIN] = true;
        }
    }
    int count = 0;
    for(auto c : seen){
        if(c) ++count;
    }
    return count;
}
```

And If you want a more general solution that works well with sparse data `sum_pairs3<int>(vec)` (0.097 second)

```cpp
template<typename T>
int sum_pairs3(const vector<T> &vec){
    unordered_set<T> seen;
    int n = vec.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++)
        {
            seen.insert(vec[i] + vec[j]);
        }
    }
    return seen.size();
}
```